# Recursive concatenation of Matlab structs

Tags: matlab

Is it somehow possible to concatenate two matlab structures recursively without iterating over all leaves of one of the structures.

For instance

> x.a=1;
>
> x.b.c=2;
>
> y.b.d=3;
>
> y.a = 4 ;

would result in the following

> res = mergeStructs(x,y)
>
> res.a=4
>
> res.b.c=2
>
> res.b.d=3

Comment: For this to work you need a decision criteria for conflicts. For example should res.a = 1 or res.a=4?

Comment: By default, the values in the second struct would overwrite the values in the first struct having the same fieldname..

Answer (score 6):

The following function works for your particular example. There will be things it doesn't consider, so let me know if there are other cases you want it to work for and I can update.

```
function res = mergeStructs(x,y)
if isstruct(x) && isstruct(y)
    res = x;
    names = fieldnames(y);
    for fnum = 1:numel(names)
        if isfield(x,names{fnum})
            res.(names{fnum}) = mergeStructs(x.(names{fnum}),y.(names{fnum}));
        else
            res.(names{fnum}) = y.(names{fnum});
        end
    end
else
    res = y;
end
```

Then `res = mergeStructs(x,y);` gives:

```
>> res.a
ans =
     4

>> res.b
ans = 
    c: 2
    d: 3
```

as you require.

EDIT: I added `isstruct(x) &&` to the first line. The old version worked fine because `isfield(x,n)` returns `0` if `~isstruct(x)`, but the new version is slightly faster if `y` is a big struct and `~isstruct(x)`.

Comment: the solution doesn't meet the "without iterating over all leaves of one of the structures" requirement

Comment: @zhanwu: Fair enough. I agree that there is both iteration and recursion at work in the above. It doesn't iterate over *all* leaves, only the leaves of `y` at a level where both `x` and `y` are structs.